# image in jumbotron is not look good when small layer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can this picture on jumbotron can look good responsive

image in jumbotron when small laye is not good, how can i fix it?
this is code that i use

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(images/fid.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
```

![Valid XHTML][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPHq0.jpg
  ![Valid XHTML][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huBP1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work or not but try it

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(images/fid.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
```